# binding nested arrays as geojson popups in leaflet

Tags: geojson, leaflet, popup

I am struggling with geojson popups in leaflet.js
I have nested arrays as properties for my features - 
an example would be counts of fish caught at a location (not my actual project data!)

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[{"geometry":{"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[-122.679416,
45.516632]},
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{"fisher_id":"401",
"river":"Willamette",
"fishcaught":[{"type":"Salmon",
"count":5},
{"type":"Sturgen",
"count":1},
{"type":"Bass",
"count":2}]}},
{"geometry":{"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[-121.318584,
44.050165]},
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{"fisher_id":"401",
"river":"Deschutes",
"fishcaught":[{"type":"Trout",
"count":10},
{"type":"Whitefish",
"count":1}]}},
{"geometry":{"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[-124.102962,
43.983057]},
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{"fisher_id":"401",
"river":"Siuslaw",
"fishcaught":[{"type":"Steelhead",
"count":2},
{"type":"Salmon",
"count":6}]}},
{"geometry":{"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[-121.776289,
42.220382]},
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{"fisher_id":"401",
"river":"Klamath",
"fishcaught":[{"type":"Trout",
"count":3},
{"type":"Steelhead",
"count":2},
{"type":"Salmon",
"count":3}]}}]}
```

I am trying to put a popup on each feature (onEachFeature) that states river and a count of each type caught.

I'm binding using a function like this

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties.fishcaught) {
            var popupcontent;
            popupcontent = "<span style='font-weight:bold'>River: </span>"+feature.properties.river
            for (i=0;i<feature.properties.fishcaught.length;i=i+1){
                var fishstring = "<br><span style='font-weight:bold'>"+feature.properties.fishcaught[i].type+": </span>"
                +feature.properties.fishcaught[i].count
                popupcontent = popupcontent+fishstring;
            }
            layer.bindPopup(popupcontent);
        }
    }

geojson = L.geoJson(inData, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

The problem is that the onEachFeature is caught in an endless loop. If I remove the for loop from the function, everything works fine.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What happens if you put a semi-colon after your popupcontent = "... lines?

Does the debug console say anything? Canyou set up a jsfiddle of this so that we can edit it?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle request. Of course, the fiddle works fine, and I have long since moved past this issue! Marking my question answered so others might see the code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever it is worth, when I revisited this, and build the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/28vwV/) it now works...
(thanks @alexgleith for the nudge!)

Marking complete so others might see the code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo in your for loop.  It should be:

```
for (i=0;i<feature.properties.fishcaught.length;i++)
```

instead of:

```
for (i=0;i<feature.properties.fishcaught.length;i=i+1)
```

Notice that the first is incrementing i by one not adding 1 to i.

Comment: i++ and i=i+1 and i+=1 all do the same thing. I come from a python background,so often default to the latter 2... http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/qHXUM/