# Adding pop-up to GeoJSON layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm new to working with the Leaflet API and am running into trouble with creating popups for a GeoJSON layer. I've looked at the following post as a reference and am still having difficulty: 
[binding nested arrays as geojson popups in leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/binding-nested-arrays-as-geojson-popups-in-leaflet)

My GeoJson data looks like:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -73.97364044189453,
                    40.66893768310547
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "lon": -73.97364044189453,
                "lat": 40.66893768310547,
                "version": "1.1",
                "t": 1381167616,
                "device": "iPhone3,3",
                "alt": 67,
                "os": "6.1.3"
            }
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -73.96121215820312,
                    40.66240692138672
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "lon": -73.96121215820312,
                "lat": 40.66240692138672,
                "version": "1.1",
                "t": 1381171200,
                "device": "iPhone3,3",
                "alt": 45,
                "os": "6.1.3"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

My leaflet js is as follows:

```
// create a variable to load Stamen 'toner' tiles
var layer = new L.StamenTileLayer("toner");

// initialize and set map center and zoom
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(40.67, -73.94),
    zoom: 12
});

// create the map 
map.addLayer(layer);

// on each feature use feature data to create a pop-up
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    if (feature.properties) {

        var popupContent;
        popupContent = feature.properties.t;

        console.log(popupContent);    
    }
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}

// grab the processed GeoJSON through ajax call
var geojsonFeature = (function() {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': "/data/test_random.json",
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();

// create an object to store marker style properties
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 10,
    fillColor: "rgb(255,0,195)",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 1
};

// load the geojson to the map with marker styling
L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {

    style: function (feature) {
        return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
    },

    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions)
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

The `console.log(popupContent);` call within the `onEachFeature` function is returning data, however when I click on the GeoJSON points in the map I get the following error:
`Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`

I've tried looking into this with no success so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example that I have of loading geojson from a WFS service: http://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/dogexerciseareas.html

This is another example loading topojson (similar, but different): http://agl.pw/examples/NRM_Regions/map.html

Here's some simple code I use to load a layer:

```
var myLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
$.getJSON("data/buildings.json", function(json) {
  myLayer.addData(json);
});
```

Then you can do interactivity and styling with something like this:

```
    success : function (response) {
        DogExerciseAreas = L.geoJson(response, {
            style: function (feature) {
                return {
                    stroke: false,
                    fillColor: 'FFFFFF',
                    fillOpacity: 0
                };
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
                layer.bindPopup("<b>Site name:</b> " + feature.properties.sitename +
                    "<br><b>Dog Exercise: </b>" + feature.properties.dog_exercise +
                    "<br><br>Please ensure that tidy up after your dog. Dogs must be kept under effective control at all times."
                    ,popupOptions);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    }
```

EDIT: an example from the leaflet website on styling points (from here http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html):

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};

L.geoJson(someGeojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

EDIT2: Added a solution to this problem. See here: https://gist.github.com/alexgleith/7112515

All you need to do now is edit the bit where it says 'popupContent' to add your bit and change the code to load data from the file.

Comment: thanks alexgleith, this seems to work and looking at your examples is helpful as well. Though how would I add the pointToLayer function that displays point data as circle markers?

Comment: Good question, I added a bit to the bottom of my post. I think you can basically do that with a style for the points that are created.

Comment: so I can get the default style markers to have working pop-ups, but not circle-markers. For some reason when I put these together it doesn't seem to work: http://pastebin.com/T9E9XpQM If you remove lines 68-70 the pop-ups work. as of now the pointToLayer function doesn't change the point style. Do I have it in the wrong place in my code?

Comment: Try addin this: .bindPopup("<b>Time:</b> " + time +
                            "<br><b>Altitude: </b>" + feature.properties.alt + "meters"
                            ,popupOptions); to the end of line 69

You are doing everything twice, I think!

Comment: then the bindPopup method cannot reference variables from onEachFeature. I think my head is spinning.

Comment: Hi Chris, you're overcomplicating things! Can you please set up a GIST for your random points and your html, I'll fix it for you and send it back.

Comment: okay, here you are: https://gist.github.com/clhenrick/7111177
much, thanks!

Comment: Added a gist with the solution. Perhaps you could try to keep your code nice and tidy in the future! You had bits everywhere! Let me know if you have any trouble getting my code working. YOu can see it here: https://rawgithub.com/alexgleith/7112515/raw/0bab1b373384b1556dbf9d268115600ed1b65e61/geojsonCircleMarker.html

Comment: added your data: https://rawgithub.com/alexgleith/7112515/raw/a63eabd833d9fb943596ef99d60761bcd9a927e7/geojsonCircleMarker.html

Comment: thanks Alex, I believe my problem was trying to get the onEachFeature function to work with the pointToLayer function inside the L.geoJson method so that I would not have to hard code the popup contents for each geoJson layer. But it looks like in your example the code works well and I could just create a global variable for popupContent. Still confused on how one would use onEachFeature with pointToLayer inside the L.geoJson method.